# how to output data from multiple files in side by side columns in one file via awk?

Tags: awk, multiple-columns

I have 30 files, called UE1.dat, UE2.dat .... with 4 columns in every of them. An example of their column structure is given below for UE1.dat and UE2.dat.

UE1.dat

```
1 4 2 1 
2 2 3 3
3 2 4 4   
4 4 4 2
```

UE2.dat

```
2 6 8 7 
4 4 9 6
7 1 1 2   
9 3 3 3
```

So, i have tried with the following code:

`for((i=1;i<=30;i++)); do awk 'NR$i {printf $1",";next} 1; END {print ""}' UE$i.dat; done > UE_all.dat`

to get only the first column from every file and write them in a single file and columns to be side by side,The desired OUTPUT is given below.

```
1 2
2 4
3 7
4 9
```

But unfortunately, the code orders them in rows, can you give a hint?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: With your output - are you just after the first column each time? How should it look for additional files - 30 columns wide, all from 'column 1' of each file? And does it have to be `awk`?

Comment: no, it is not necessary to be awk, but i used that in that case. I have just edited the question, so you can check the desired output there. Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably go with something like - using `perl` rather than `awk` because I prefer the handling of data structures. In this case - we use a two dimensional array, insert the first column of each file into a new column of the array, then print the whole thing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $num_files = 2; 

my @rows;
my $count = 0; 
my $max = 0; 

for my $filenum ( 1..$num_files ) {
    open ( my $input, "<", "UE${filenum}.dat" ) or die $!;
    while ( <$input> ) {
        my @fields = split;
        push ( @{$rows[$filenum]}, $fields[0] );
        $count++;
    } 
    close ( $input ); 
    if ( $count > $max ) { $max = $count };
}

print Dumper \@rows;

for ( 0..$count ) { 
    foreach my $filenum ( 1..$num_files ) {
       print shift @{$rows[$filenum]} || ''," ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: it gives me: Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at ./script line 24 ??I can not see any inconsistency on line 24.

Comment: Ah yes, Sorry, perl starts arrays at zero. So you might need;  `@columns[1..30] ` (answer edited)

Comment: Sorry, edited again - hopefully this one's a bit better.

Comment: this time doesn't work :), it prints only the first three columns with strange space between them. But the previous version works :)

Comment: this is the first line of the output:                                                            $VAR1 = [
          undef,
          [

Comment: Comment out that `Dumper` line - that's for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

In awk you can do it this way:

1) Put this code in a file named `output_data_from_multiple_files.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    # All the input files are processed in one run.
    # filenumber counts the number of input files.
    filenumber = 1
}

{
    # FNR is the input record number in the current input file.
    # Concatenate the value of the first column in the corresponding
    # line in the output.
    output[FNR] = output[FNR] " " $1

    # FNR == 1 means we are processing a new file.
    if (FNR == 1) {
        ++filenumber
    }
}

END {
    # print the output
    for (i=1; i<=FNR; i++)
        printf("%s\n", output[i])
}
```

2) Run `awk -f output_data_from_multiple_files.awk UE*`

All the files are handled in a single execution of `awk`. `FNR` is the input record number in the current input file. `filenumber` is used to count the number of processed files. The values read in the input files are concatenated in the `output` array.

Comment: also works, but there are some strange tabs between different columns. Thank you!

Comment: @TrifonGetsov That's strange, the script inserts only one space when concatenating the values. Well in fact I didn't execute it like that, I put the code in a file. I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate all of the columns into one file with an `awk` associative array:

```
# use a wildcard to get all the files (could also use a for-loop)
# add each new row to the array using line number as an index
# at the end of reading all files, go through each index (will be 1-4 in 
# your example) and print index, and then the fully concatenated rows
awk '{a[FNR] = a[FNR]" "$0}END{ for (i in a) print i, a[i] | "sort -k1n"}' allfiles*
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is this

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{f++}{print FNR,f,$1}' UE* | sort -nk 1,2 | cut -d" " -f3 | xargs -L $(ls UE*.dat | wc -l)
```

This is how I got to it... I number the lines and files using `gawk`, then sort them by line number, then secondly by file, simply using `sort` and remove the file and line numbers. So...

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{f++}{print FNR,f,$1}' UE*

1 1 1  # line 1 file 1 is 1
2 1 2  # line 2 file 1 is 2
3 1 3  # line 3 file 1 is 3
4 1 4  # line 4 file 1 is 4
1 2 2  # line 1 file 2 is 2
2 2 4  # line 2 file 2 is 4
3 2 7  # line 3 file 2 is 7
4 2 9  # line 4 file 2 is 9
```

Then use `sort` like this to put the first line of file 1 followed by the first line of file 2, first line of file n, second line of file 1, second line of file 2, second line of file n. Then get the third column:

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{f++}{print FNR,f,$1}' UE* | sort -nk 1,2 | cut -d" " -f3
1
2
2
4
3
7
4
9
```

And then put them back together with `xargs`

```
gawk 'BEGINFILE{f++}{print FNR,f,$1}' UE* | sort -nk 1,2 | cut -d" " -f3 | xargs -L2
1 2
2 4
3 7
4 9
```

The `-L2` at the end must match the number of files, i.e. `-L30` in your case.